# How to access the context in Test Activity while using Mockito and Dagger 2

Tags: android, mockito, android-espresso, dagger-2

I have a class `String.java` which has a method

```
public String getTermsandCondition(Context context) {
String versionName = SystemUtils.getAppVersionName(context);
return "version:"+ versionName;
}
```

So i'm using this method in my `MainActivity.Java` like this `string.getTermsandCondition(this)`

When i'm using this same method in my `MainActivityTest.Java` like this 
`Mockito.when(getString.getTermsandCondition(copyRight.getActivity())).thenReturn("Term&Conditions");`

But i'm getting error when matching 
`onView(withId(R.id.message)).check(matches(withText("Term&Conditions")));`

So my question is how to pass the context from `MainActivityTest.Java` in `getString.getTermsandCondition(copyRight.getActivity())`

```
public class MainActivityTest{

@Inject
CopyrightString getString;


@Rule
public IntentsTestRule<MainActivity> copyRight = new IntentsTestRule<>(MainActivity.class, true, false);

@Before
public void setUp() {
    Instrumentation instrumentation = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation();
    Application app
            = (Application) instrumentation.getTargetContext().getApplicationContext();
    CopyrightTestComponent component = (CopyrightTestComponent) app.component();
    component.inject(this);
}

@Test
public void ensureMsgShows() {
    Mockito.when(getString.getTermsandCondition(copyRight.getActivity())).thenReturn("Term&Conditions");
    copyRight.launchActivity(new Intent());
    onView(withId(R.id.message)).check(matches(withText("Term&Conditions")));
}

@Test
public void ensureAcceptClick() {
    copyRight.launchActivity(new Intent());
    onView(withText("Accept")).perform(click());
    intended((hasComponent(NextActivity.class.getName())));
}
}
```

This is my `MainActivity.Java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Inject
CopyrightString string ;


 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_copyright);
 ((Application) getApplication()).component().inject(this);
 ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.message)).setText(string.getTermsandCondition(this));

 }
```

This is my `CopyrightString.Java`

```
 @Singleton
 public class CopyrightString {

 public String getTermsandCondition(Context context) {
    String versionName = SystemUtils.getAppVersionName(context);
    return "version:"+ versionName;
}

@Module
public class CopyrightStringModule {

@Provides
@Singleton
CopyrightString provideGetTerm$Condition(){
    return new CopyrightString();
   }
}


@Singleton
@Component(modules = {CopyrightStringModule.class})

public  interface MyAppComponent{

void inject (MainActivity activity);
}


@Singleton
@Component(modules = {MockCopyrightStringModule.class})

public interface CopyrightTestComponent extends MyAppComponent {
void inject(MainActivityTest activityTest);
}

public class Application extends Application {


@Singleton
@Component(modules = {CopyrightStringModule.class})

public interface appComponent extends MyAppComponent {

}

private final MyAppComponent component = createComponent();

protected MyAppComponentcreateComponent() {
    return DaggerMyAppComponent.builder()
            .copyrightStringModule(new CopyrightStringModule())
            .build();
}

public MyAppComponent component() {
    return component;
}


@Singleton
@Component(modules = {MockCopyrightStringModule.class})

public interface CopyrightTestComponent extends MyAppComponent {
void inject(MainActivityTest activityTest);
}

@Module
public class MockCopyrightStringModule {

@Provides
@Singleton
CopyrightString provideGetTerm$Condition(){

    return Mockito.mock(CopyrightString.class);
   }
}
```

Comment: Post more code, how are your mocks set up?

Comment: can you just do `any(Context.class)` instead?

Comment: @DavidRawson  I've edited my question kindly check

Comment: "But i'm getting error when matching" What is the error?

Comment: Also, can you show a complete test case? You should include the `MainActivityTest` class and the single method for the test as well as any `@BeforeTest` and `@AfterTest` methods.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice edited my question

Comment: You are missing some declarations. What are `copyRight`, `CopyrightString`, and `CopyrightTestComponent`?

Comment: You also have a variable named `getString` which is never used.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice i'm using `(getString.getTermsandCondition(copyRight.getActivity()`

Comment: Finally i solved it myself.Thanks

Comment: Feel free to post an answer.

Comment: @osamaAftab can you post your own answer?

Comment: @OsamaAftabc can you post answer to this ?